# update tablerates bug

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, table-rates

I have problem to update tablerates.csv in a webshop, I have a tablerates.csv like:

```
NOR,*,*,1000.0000,210.0000
NOR,*,*,3000.0000,462.5000
NOR,*,*,15000.0000,312.5000
NOR,*,*,20000.0000,350.0000
NOR,*,*,25000.0000,375.0000
```

It ignores all prices between 1000 to 3000 and take 210 as the shipping price. so I to change it to :

```
NOR,*,*,1000.0000,210.0000
NOR,*,*,15000.0000,312.5000
NOR,*,*,20000.0000,350.0000
NOR,*,*,25000.0000,375.0000
NOR,*,*,3000.0000,462.5000
```

and import the csv file, no error appear. But the rate didn't change, and I export the cvs file again, it showed me the same cvs file as beginning. (I don't have problem to change any amount in it.)

Comment: magento is very specific about the .csv, you must export the csv from magento, and edit it in Notepad and save it as .csv... other editors like Microsoft Excel put in extra data which Magento classifies as corrupt. I think that's the problem.. try editing the file with Notepad.

Comment: I used notepad++, I can change the amount, but I cannot change the order of lines.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the order in the CSV file doesn't matter, since Magento will sort it internally before processing it. You say it ignores prices between 1000 and 3000 and takes 210 as the shipping price. Well, this is expected behavior since the price you put in the 4th column is a 'From' price.

That is why you should also add a row with a '0' value in the 4th column; using the CSV you've put in, products that cost less than 1000 NOR will have free shipping.

You'll also need a header in the CSV file to let Magento know what is what.

Change the CSV content to;

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"
NOR,*,*,0.0000,100.0000
NOR,*,*,1000.0000,210.0000
NOR,*,*,3000.0000,462.5000
NOR,*,*,15000.0000,312.5000
NOR,*,*,20000.0000,350.0000
NOR,*,*,25000.0000,375.0000
```

I've taken 100 NOR as the shipping cost for products that cost less than 1000 NOR. So a product with a price of 1500 NOR falls between the 1000 and 3000 steps, which will take the shipping cost associated with the lower bound, which is 210 NOR.

We've also created a small tool that'll explain the table rates system a bit and will help you creating a CSV with a GUI. You can find it here; http://elgentos.nl/tablerates